# Android:Unable to get String Resource

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to use a cursorAapter to bindview two strings to a textView. However I seem to be getting a Resources not found exception. I don't understand why as they are both 2 string types and I am making an entry at the beginning of the program so there will be something to display.

LogCat

```
10-21 19:44:51.042: E/AndroidRuntime(14930): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:200)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2813)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at com.example.mycoursetimetable.TestCursorAdapter.bindView(TestCursorAdapter.java:28)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-21 19:44:51.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14930):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 19:44:51.082: I/dalvikvm(14930): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
```

Main Activty

```
public class MyCourses extends Activity {

    static final String TEST = "com.example.mycoursetimetable.TEST";
    database MODULEDATABASE;  
    ListView listContent;
    Cursor cursor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_courses);

       listContent =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       MODULEDATABASE = new database(MyCourses.this);

       MODULEDATABASE.createEntry("TestCode", "TestName");

       MODULEDATABASE.openToRead(); // don't forget this part!
       cursor = MODULEDATABASE.getData();

       listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       TestCursorAdapter ca = new TestCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
       listContent.setAdapter(ca);

        }

}
```

Cursor Adapter

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater viewInflater;

    public TestCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        viewInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        TextView text_moduleId = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelDay);
        TextView text_modulecode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelModuleCode);
        TextView text_modulename = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelEditModuleFull);

        //text_moduleId.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_ROWID)));
        text_modulecode.setText(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULECODE));
        text_modulename.setText(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULENAME));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcourses, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

}
```

database snippet

```
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE +  " (" +
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        KEY_MODULECODE + " TEXT, " +
                        KEY_MODULENAME + " TEXT); "
                    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABEL IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public database(Context c){
        myContext = c;
    }

    public  database openToWrite()throws SQLException{
        myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
        moduleDatabase = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public  database openToRead()throws SQLException{
        myHelper = new DbHelper(myContext);
        moduleDatabase = myHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
    myHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String moduleCode, String moduleName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MODULECODE,moduleCode);
        cv.put(KEY_MODULENAME,moduleName);
        return moduleDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Cursor getData() {

        String[] columns = new String [] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_MODULECODE, KEY_MODULENAME};
        Cursor c = moduleDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        return c;
    }


}
```

Comment: are you sure that textviews id are correct?

Comment: Which is the line 28 in your adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guerss this line is the problem:

```
 text_modulecode.setText(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULECODE));
```

the columnIndex is most likely an int, which is interpreted as a resourceId. Thats why it is searching for resource ID 1 (the column index). Use

```
....setText(String.valueOf(c.getColumnIndex(database.KEY_MODULECODE)));
```

to make sure you use the method that takes a String.

Comment: thanks, that solved one problem, i think. I'm now getting a null pointer exception relating to the return type of my createEntry method?

Comment: if you want to return a Long (object type) with a null value, it tries to auto-unbox it to a long (primitive type), which results in a NullPointerException.

Comment: I converted it a void method with no return type but I still get an error relating the NullPointerException moduleDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);

Comment: Then I would suggest debugging into the method and see what exactly throws it.

Comment: You're awesome man! Lol still making those mistakes in  2016 :-D